# get the cost time of finishing a game in PHP & javascript

Tags: javascript, php, time

I want to get the cost time for a player to finish a task.
so at the beginning in php `$timestart=time();` and then after the game finish, the player click the submit button, so in javascript: `

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var taskid=num;
    var guessnum=$("input[name=guessnum]:checked").val();
    finishedTask += 1; 
    var starttime=$("#timestart").val();
    var d = new Date();
    var endtime = d.getTime();
    var timecost=endtime/1000-starttime;
})
```

For #timestart, it is inside the form
 `<input type="hidden" name="timestart" id="timestart" value="<?echo $timestart; ?>">`

Thanks for your guys' reply. So  I need to get the finish time from server.When the player submit the result, it could be transferred and deal by the database, can I take the database read data from $_POST[..] this time moment as the finish time?

Cheers,

Comment: Better to use PHP time on submit button as well because Js use client's System time that may be different from server time so make an AJAX call to PHP page and return time(); from there.

Comment: You mean you change servers during the process or the entire process is run on a different server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are reading the client time and comparing it with server time. If the clocks are set differently on the two computers then you will always get the wrong result.

You should never really trust anything running on the client computer anyway (it's easily hacked) so the best approach is to just both record the start time and calculate the duration server side.